# Prove a set is countable if it doesn't contain any of its limit points

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$, if $A\cap A'=\phi$. Then A is countable. The hint given is to use that any collection of disjoint open intervals is countable.

How do I make use of the hint?

I was also thinking that such a set would have to be a set of isolated points but I am not able to arrive at it mathematically.

Comment: I suppose that $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$, not the closure of $A$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yeah, thank you. Corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\in A$, then there exists $\varepsilon_a>0$ such that $(a-\varepsilon_a,a+\varepsilon_a)\cap A=\{a\}$; otherwise, if for every $\varepsilon>0$, $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\cap A$ contains at least $2$ points, then $a$ is a limit point of $A$ which is a contradiction. Thus every $a\in A$ is an isolated point, so $A$ is countable.